# What is a(n) conjunction/phrase/adverb that means the same as "if we ignore X, ... (the rest is good)" in writings?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, adverbs, conjunctions

Example: "**If we overlook** the fact that the game lacks purpose, I think it's safe to say it's an amazing pastime."

I think "apart from" could be misunderstood and perceived as "besides" here. That's why I'd prefer to use something more definite.

Also, "except (for)", while correct, seems less like something a professional writer would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about these options:

> **Disregarding** the fact that the game lacks purpose, I think it's safe to say it's an amazing pastime.

> **Although** the game lacks purpose, I think it's safe to say it's an amazing pastime.

I think one would normally use a simple adversative conjunction like *although* in examples such as yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Disregarding" is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Also possibly "notwithstanding", which is slightly more formal:

> Notwithstanding the game's lack of purpose, it's an amazing pastime.

https://www.wordreference.com/definition/notwithstanding

An alternative approach might be to add a concessive to the second clause, perhaps "nevertheless" or "in spite of this"

> The game lacks purpose; nevertheless it's an amazing pastime.
>
> The game lacks purpose. This notwithstanding, it's an amazing pastime.
>
> The game lacks purpose, but in spite of this, it's an amazing pastime.

Some other ideas at https://www.wordreference.com/synonyms/notwithstanding

Comment: Much appreciated. This will definitely come in handy in formal writings.